# SQL coalesce - other ways to populate merged values in the resulting output?

Tags: sql, sas, full-outer-join

I want to join two tables like

```
have1
key ...
a   ...
b   ...
c   ...

have2
key ...
a   ...
c   ...
d   ...
```

and get output like

```
want
key ...
a   ...
b   ...
c   ...
d   ...
```

I know that

```
create table want as 
  select coalesce(a.key, b.key) as key, ..., 
  from have1 a full join have2 b 
  on a.key=b.key;
```

Will give me the output, but are there alternatives? I would like to have more concise and readable code, and joining on 3 or 4 conditions seems to take a lot of text to achieve the desired output (relative to, say, the SAS data step).

Comment: Are the key variables the only common variables?  Did you try `NATURAL` join?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`:

```
select h1.*
from have1 h1
union all
select h2.*
from h2
where not exists (select 1 from have1 h1 where h1.key = h2.key);
```

Answer (score 0):

In many databases, you can disambiguate the joining column with the `using` syntax:

```
create table want as 
select key, ..., 
from have1 a 
full join have2 b using (key)
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION operator is what you want. It automatically removes duplicates.

```
data have1;
input key $;
cards;
a
b
c
;;;;
run;

data have2;
input key $;
cards;
a
b 
d
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as 
select * from 
have1 union select * from have2;
quit;

proc print data=want;
run;
```